# Javascript change specific object properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this:

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: myURL
}).
success(function (data, status) {
    $scope.data = data.content; //complex object
    for(i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){
        $scope.data[i].value1 = "newvalue1";
        $scope.data[i].value2= "newvalue2";
    }
});
```

How can I change the property in a certain point of an array of objects?

I get this error, even if I know it exists

```
$scope.data[i] is undefined
```

I tried to parse the JSON, but I get this error

```
unexpected character found...
```

Comment: What is `data.content`?

Comment: Please post the JSON so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: myURL
}).
success(function (data, status) {
    $scope.data = data.content; //complex object
    for(i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){
        var x = $scope.data[i];
        x.value1 = "newvalue1";
        x.value2= "newvalue2";
        $scope.data[i].value1 = x.value1;
        $scope.data[i].value2 = x.value2;
    }
});
```

to be honest, I don't know why it works this way, but it does.
Thank you everybody.

**EDIT 04/2018**

I was giving a look to my old questions...a better way to to this with AngularJS would be the following:

```
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: myURL
    }).
    then(function (response) {
        /**
         * Remember to use clear identifiers
         * to always see what is in a variable
         * without having to investigate each time
         */
        $scope.myObjectList = response.content;

        /**
         * If I remember correctly, 
         * response.content was an array of objects,
         * used to print some page in the view (ng-repeat)
         */
         var i = -1
         while(++i<$scope.myObjectList.length){
            angular.extend($scope.myObjectList[i], {
                value1: "newvalue1",
                value2: "newvalue2"
            });
         }
         /**
          * angular.forEach would also be an option,
          * or _.each if you have lodash 
          */
    }, function(error){
        //Don't forget to handle errors!
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

use use this if `$scope.data` has array of object:

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: myURL
}).
success(function (data, status) {
    $scope.data = data.content; //complex object
    for(var key in $scope.data){
        $scope.data[key].value1 = "newvalue1";
        $scope.data[key].value2= "newvalue2";
    }
});
```

or if value1 and value2 is already a key of $scope.data like

```
$scope.data = {
    value1: "me"
    value2: "you"
}
```

then use this:

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: myURL
}).
success(function(data, status) {
    $scope.data = data.content; //complex object
    for (var key in $scope.data) {
        if (key == 'value1') {
            $scope.data[key]= "newvalue1";
        }

    }
});
```